# Golang interface reference to nil pointer

Tags: go

Tengo una funcion que recibe como parametro una interfaz:

```
type SayHello interface {
    Hello()
}
```

Por otro lado tengo dos Structs, donde una embebe a la otra y la Struct hija implementa la interfaz:

```
type Struct1 struct {
    Name string
}

type Struct2 struct {
    Name  string
    Child *Struct1
}

func (s1 *Struct1) Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hi im struct1")
}
```

En mi bloque principal instancio Struct2 sin pasarle una referencia a Struct1 (esta queda en ):

```
func main() {
    s := &Struct2{
        Name: "FooBar",
    }

    if s.Child != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}
```

Si corro ese bloque de codigo la respuesta es:

```
Inside function Pointer IS nil
```

Lo cual es correcto.

Ahora agrego una funcion que recibe como parametro la interfaz SayHello:

```
func Process(s SayHello) {
    if s != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
        s.Hello()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}
```

Si llamo a dicha funcion en el bloque pr

```
func main() {
    s := &Struct2{
        Name: "FooBar",
    }

    if s.Child != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }

    Process(s.Child)
}
```

Obtengo:

```
Inside function Pointer IS nil
Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil
Hi im struct1
```

Donde se ve que no solo el parametro no es  como deberia ser, sino que incluso llama al metodo de *Struct1

Si agrego una funcion donde el parametro sea del tipo *Struct1 esta si se comporta adecuadamente:

```
func main() {
    s := &Struct2{
        Name: "FooBar",
    }

    if s.Child != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }

    Process(s.Child)
    Process2(s.Child)
}

func Process(s SayHello) {
    if s != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
        s.Hello()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}

func Process2(s *Struct1) {
    if s != nil {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}
```

Respuesta:

```
Inside function Pointer IS nil
Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil
Hi im struct1
Inside function Pointer IS nil
```

Por que sucede esto?

Como puedo checkear en:

```
func Process(s SayHello)
```

que el parametro efectivamente es nil?

Ejemplo funcional en:

https://go.dev/play/p/ZPLjNz1eo1L

Comment: Estás en StackOverflow en ESPAÑOL, deberías [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla. También sería aconsejable que pases por [ask] y realices el [tour]

Comment: Además de traducir tu pregunta, no olvides que el código va _como texto, con formato, en la pregunta_.

Comment: Modificado, gracias por el feedback

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta a tu pregunta es:

> Una comparativa de `s != nil` te dará siempre `true` porque una interfaz contiene el valor y el tipo de dato.

En tu caso, te interesa saber si el valor es `nil`, por lo que técnicamente tienes dos opciones, hacer un `cast` al tipo de dato o usar reflexión.

Con reflexión (reflection):

```golang
func Process(s SayHello) {
    if reflect.ValueOf(s).IsNil() {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
        s.Hello()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}
```

Haciendo un cast:

```golang
func Process(s SayHello) {
    switch v := s.(type) {

    case (*Struct1):
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS NOT nil")
        s.Hello()
    default:
        fmt.Println("Inside function Pointer IS nil")
    }
}
```

Esta última en realidad es muy poco práctica, porque tendrías que agregar al `switch` un `case` para cada struct que implemente dicha interfaz.